# How to Link PHP Script with JavaScript and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to take a CSV file from the client side and read it in order to create arrays that can then be used in my original html file, that contains javascript, to create a dynamic table. My PHP code for parsing into arrays is:

```
<php?
$csvData = file_get_contents($fileName);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

And my HTML (a simple file upload) is:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload CSV" name="submit">
```

but I am unsure as to how I should connect these pieces? Can the PHP script be in the same document as the HTML(which contains the JS to construct the table), or should it be called through a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your php script in a file eg. upload.php.
Then use the following code in your html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload CSV" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: And to access the arrays built, can i simply use a json function? And how would the user return to the original page without losing php data from the file?

Comment: You can ajax to post the file . The you don't need to worry about  redirecting. The content can be access by using the name file element eg. "fileToUpload". You can test it print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload']);

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to output the csv based on Reagan Gallant's suggestion above, is to print the data directly from upload.php. You can also add a header saying that you're serving csv, and let the browser decide what to do (save as file, display in browser):

`header('Content-Type: text/csv');
print $csv;`

Or you can use a javascript library such as JQuery to upload the file and return the result using ajax. This requires a little bit extra coding, but depending on your goal it might be worthwhile.

Comment: The header/print statement would be inserted into upload.php, and is used at the end. Keep in mind that the call to `header` must be the first output from the script, otherwise the call will fail. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll check that out!